# Physical Keyboard and Mouse controlled via Internet or other PC?

Tags: windows, admin, remote-access

Imagine this crazy setup:
There are two PCs (Windows) in a network. Lets call them PC-1 and PC-2
PC-1 can use Remote Desktop software (TeamViewer, etc.) and PC-2 can´t.

The goal is to "emulate" remote access to PC-2.
Here is what I have thought of:

I use the video-in of PC-1 to access the screen of PC-2, and simply connect to PC-1 via some remote desktop software.

The only problem is I need physical access to a keyboard and mouse on PC-2.
Are there any keyboard/mouse combos (dongles) available that can be controlled from a different PC. Its like a pass-through system.

Normally a dongle works like this: keyboard/mouse input -> dongle -> input in windows. But I need it the other way around. "Windows" should send data to the dongle which is connected to PC-2.

Would be nice if you come up with another solution. I know its weird, but Remote Software does not work on PC-2.

Comment: logitech unifying receiver. 1 mouse, 2 PCs.

Comment: The thing is that it needs to transmit the virtual input of the remote session to the dongle.

Answer (score -1):

You could build your own so that the dongle can be connected to PC-1 using Bluetooth, and make a program to sent the coordinates of the mouse to the Bluetooth dongle. I do not know about any such products on the market however.